# slide component?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider

So is there a component out there that everyone is using or is are all these types of slider components just built from scratch?  You see these on a lot of startups websites.  Maybe someone knows of a tut or can help me get started?

Examples:

http://flipboard.com/
http://gigwalk.com/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of them are done with one of the infinite [jQuery Slider Plugins](http://www.google.com/search?q=jquery%20slider%20plugin). You could try this one (http://bxslider.com/), but you have quite a selection to choose from.

If you don't know much JavaScript or jQuery, I'd suggest reading [Getting Started with jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aGetting_Started_with_jQuery). It's a nice intro.

Answer (score 1):

I use this easy to use little JQuery plugin..

http://cssglobe.com/post/3783/jquery-plugin-easy-image-or-content-slider

Comment: "This is my first jQuery plugin." - author of said article.  I would be cautious about using this plugin.

Comment: I don't intend to destroy this author's work, which is why I changed my comment from 'advise against using' to 'be cautious about using' this plug-in.  It has seen some improvements: http://cssglobe.com/post/5780/easy-slider-17-numeric-navigation-jquery-slider.  You really should update your link to include the current version.  I felt that a caution was in order and gave it; that's all.

Comment: No worries, wasn't harassing you I actually stumbled upon that one today and it seems to work well.

Answer (score 1):

**As always, I recommend using the [jquery cycle plug-in](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/).**  Although the website has some pretty poorly designed examples in terms of aesthetics, the plug-in has many options and is in use by plenty of professional websites.  It lets you use all sorts of markup with plenty of effects available to you.